# htaccess non-www to www while http to https and http://www to https://www

Tags: .htaccess

Basically, i want to have these

- non-www to www
- http to https
- http://domain.com to http://www.domain.com

My current htaccess is this.

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?url=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}$1
```

It works fine this way, but when you manually go to `http://domain.com`, and change it to `https://domain.com`, it added two sets of index.php.

Any ideas please?

Comment: I'm confused. If http goes to https, and non-www goes to www, then `http://domain.com` should go to `https://www.domain.com` right? Both https and www applied.

Comment: exactly my point, which is not happening using this current htaccess i have. well partly. as it adds two sets of index.php if you manually go edit the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can see to be an issue with your code is that you have `$1` on the `WWW` and `HTTPS` redirects, which would add the request URI path at the end twice, since you already have `%{REQUEST_URI}`:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}:443%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?url=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Also it would be easier if you first redirect `HTTP` to `HTTPS` (if needed) and then check whether or not the `WWWW` is missing to redirect (again if needed).

Could probably leave the `HTTPS` rule without `[R=301,L]` but if the URL is already right we want to avoid processing more rules.

***Keep in mind that the ORDER of your rules is very important.***

Comment: ok so so close. when url is https:// www and you manually remove www from it, it returns the https:// www back with no added index.php which is good. but now if the url is https and you manually remove S from it it will return http without the S on it.. i really appreciate the help

Comment: that fixed it. its exactly what i want to accomplish. thank you!