# Rewrite URL Sub directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to redirect non-www URL to www.
I have one main wordpress website `example.com` and an other website in a subdirectory `example.com/sub

The redirection from `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com` works
BUT
The redirection from `https://example.com/sub` to `https://www.example.com/sub` does not.

Main HTaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Sub htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sub/
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https
RewriteRule .* - [E=WPR_SSL:-https]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteRule .* - [E=WPR_ENC:_gzip]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !(wordpress_logged_in_.+|wp-postpass_|wptouch_switch_toggle|comment_author_|comment_author_email_) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/sub(/(.+/)?feed/?.+/?|/(?:.+/)?embed/|/(index\.php/)?wp\-json(/.*|$)))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^(facebookexternalhit).* [NC]
RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sub/wp-content/cache/wp-rocket/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/index%{ENV:WPR_SSL}%{ENV:WPR_WEBP}.html%{ENV:WPR_ENC}" -f
RewriteRule .* "/sub/wp-content/cache/wp-rocket/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/index%{ENV:WPR_SSL}%{ENV:WPR_WEBP}.html%{ENV:WPR_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /sub/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /sub/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very similar to this question that was asked recently: [.htaccess redirect entire site from non-www/http to www/https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69936763/htaccess-redirect-entire-site-from-non-www-http-to-www-https)

When the problem is per-directory `.htaccess` files, you can prevent the rules in those files from running after some rules by using the `[END]` flag.  From the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end):

> Using the `[END]` flag terminates not only the current round of rewrite processing (like `[L]`) but also prevents any subsequent rewrite processing from occurring in per-directory (`htaccess`) context.

So you should be able to use `[END]` in your rules to make them take precedence over other rules in the subdirectories:

```sh
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,END]
```

Comment: But... this will make no difference. When used with a `R=3xx` (NB: 3xx status) flag it makes no difference whether you use `L` or `END` here. (The `END` flag does not change "precedence".) With the rules as written, the mod_rewrite directives in the subdirectory override the parent directives, so the non-www to www redirect in the root is never processed. [See my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69963437/369434) (Hhhmm, why was this "accepted"?!)

Answer (score 1):

The non-www to www redirect in the root `.htaccess` file is not processed so the redirect never occurs.

mod_rewrite directives are not inherited (by default) so when you request `https://example.com/sub/`, the mod_rewrite directives in `/sub/.htaccess` completely override the parent directives (ie. the non-www to www redirect) and the parent directives are not even processed so the redirect does not occur. (In this instance, if the parent directives did get processed then your site would most certainly break anyway.)

You need to repeat the non-www to www redirect in the `/sub/.htaccess` file. However, you can't use exactly the same rule (using a backreference) in the subdirectory since you will lose the `/sub` directory from the redirect. You need to make use of the `REQUEST_URI` server variable instead.

For example, at the top of your `/sub/.htaccess` file:

```
# /sub/.htaccess

# Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Note that the `REQUEST_URI` server variable includes the slash prefix, so the slash is omitted from the *substitution* string.